# how to get how many messages failed during particular time iot hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

We have around 1millions devices connected to Azure IOT hub. Sometimes we see that there are spikes and connected devices count drop. I would like to know how many messages got failed during the any particular time? Or during a time interval?

Is there any way, or any stream queries that can be fired to get the message drop or message failed count? Hope the question is understood.

Please help if there is any link or with any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure IoT Hub can be integrated for Eventing, Logs and Diagnostics purposes to the stream pipeline pushing a source interest events to the Event Hub such as:

- subscribing to the Azure Event Grid for Azure IoT Hub event types such as *Microsoft.Devices.DeviceConnected* and *Microsoft.Devices.DeviceDisconnected*,
  more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid).
- setting a *Diagnostic settings* for metrics/logs streaming to the Event Hub,
  more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics).

The stream pipeline can be analyzed using a Stream Analytics job.